# Pickle alternatives

Tags: python, serialization

I am trying to serialize a large (~10**6 rows, each with ~20 values) list, to be used later by myself (so pickle's lack of safety isn't a concern).

Each row of the list is a tuple of values, derived from some SQL database. So far, I have seen `datetime.datetime`, strings, integers, and NoneType, but I might eventually have to support additional data types.

For serialization, I've considered pickle (cPickle), json, and plain text - but only pickle saves the type information: json can't serialize `datetime.datetime`, and plain text has its obvious disadvantages.

However, cPickle is pretty slow for data this large, and I'm looking for a faster alternative.

Comment: Have you considered dumping it into an SQLite database?

Comment: Actually - I haven't. Might be the simplest...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should give [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org/) a look. It should be ridiculously fast, at least faster than using an RDBMS, since it's very lax and doesn't impose any read/write restrictions, plus you get a better interface for managing your data, at least compared to pickling it.

Answer (score 16):

Pickle is actually quite fast so long as you aren't using the (default) ASCII protocol.  Just make sure to dump using `protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`.

Comment: It should be noted that for `python3` the default format is actually binary, according to the docs. http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#pickle

Comment: A semantically better alternative is `protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`

Comment: Thanks, @moose! Updated from `protocol=-1`.

Comment: as in `pickle.dump(data, file, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`

Comment: The highest protocol keeps on changing, and any negative number uses highest protocol. If you persist something in highest protocol in python 3.8 which is 4 (it was 3 in 3.7), upgrade to some later python which uses protocol 5 as highest protocol, you will have problems deserializing it

Answer (score 9):

- [Protocol Buffer](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial) - e.g. used in [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/); maintains type information, but you have to put quite much effort in it compared to pickle
- [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/): See [python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/msgpack-python/) - supports streaming ([source](http://pynash.org/2013/02/13/messagepack-streaming.html))
- [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/): see [python package docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/)

Depending on what exactly you want to store, there are other alternatives:

- [Apache Feather](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/feather.html)
- [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html)
- [Apache Parquet](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html)

The way to compare those is:

- Ease of use / Programming language support / Tooling support
- Being readable by a human
- Storage size
- Read-time
- Write-time
- Features: (1) Append data (2) Read single row (3) having a schema

Answer (score 7):

> Protocol buffers are a flexible, efficient, automated mechanism for
>   serializing structured data – think XML, but smaller, faster, and
>   simpler.
>
> advantages over XML:
>
> - are simpler
> - are 3 to 10 times smaller
> - are 20 to 100 times faster
> - are less ambiguous
> - generate data access classes that are easier to use programmatically

https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial

Answer (score 3):

For hundreds of thousands of simple (up to JSON-compatible) complexity Python objects, I've found the best combination of simplicity, speed, and size by combining:

- [py-ubjson](https://github.com/Iotic-Labs/py-ubjson)
- [gzip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html)

It beats `pickle` and `cPickle` options by orders of magnitude.

```
with gzip.open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    ubjson.dump(items, f)


with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    return ubjson.load(f)
```

Comment: items not defined

Comment: I suppose item=pandas dataframe

Comment: `items` is any JSON compatible object in Python

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness - there is also `dill` library that extends `pickle`.

[How to dill (pickle) to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168420/how-to-dill-pickle-to-file)

Answer (score 2):

I usually serialize to plain text (*.csv) because I found it to be fastest. The *csv* module works quite well. See http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

If you have to deal with unicode for your strings, check out the UnicodeReader and UnicodeWriter examples at the end.

If you serialize for your own future use, I guess it would suffice to know that you have the same data type per csv column (e.g., string are always on column 2).

Comment: That's not so good for me - since it doesn't maintain type information, I have to loop over the data and convert it, which is very slow (at least in my implementation, using a list comprehension of list comprehensions).

Answer (score 1):

[Avro](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/index.html) seems to be promising and properly designed but yet non popular solution.