# How to dill (pickle) to file?

Tags: python, dill

The question may seem a little basic, but wasn't able to find anything that I understood in the internet. How do I store something that I pickled with dill?

I have come this far for saving my construct (pandas DataFrame, which also contains custom classes):

```
import dill
dill_file = open("data/2017-02-10_21:43_resultstatsDF", "wb")
dill_file.write(dill.dumps(resultstatsDF))
dill_file.close()
```

and for reading

```
dill_file = open("data/2017-02-10_21:43_resultstatsDF", "rb")
resultstatsDF_out = dill.load(dill_file.read())
dill_file.close()
```

but I when reading I get the error

```
TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
```

How do I do this?

---

**EDIT for future readers:** After having used this approach (to pickle my DataFrame) for while, now I refrain from doing so. As it turns out, different program versions (including objects that might be stored in the dill file) might result in not being able to recover the pickled file. Now I make sure that everything that I want to save, can be expressed as a string (as efficiently as possible) -- actually a human readable string. Now, I store my data as CSV. Objects in CSV-cells might be represented by JSON format. That way I make sure that my files will be readable in the months and years to come. Even if code changes, I am able to rewrite encoders by parsing the strings and I am able to understand the CSV my inspecting it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm running into similar issues

Comment: @PeterSmit: I am glad it helped! You can leave an upvote :-).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just give it the file without the `read`:

```
resultstatsDF_out = dill.load(dill_file)
```

you can also dill to file like this:

```
with open("data/2017-02-10_21:43_resultstatsDF", "wb") as dill_file:
    dill.dump(resultstatsDF, dill_file)
```

So:

```
dill.dump(obj, open_file)
```

writes to a file directly. Whereas:

```
dill.dumps(obj)
```

serializes `obj` and you can write it to file yourself.

Likewise:

```
dill.load(open_file)
```

reads from a file, and:

```
dill.loads(serialized_obj)
```

constructs an object form a serialized object, which you could read from a file.

It is recommended to open a file using the `with` statement.

Here:

```
with open(path) as fobj:
    # do somdthing with fobj
```

has the same effect as:

```
fobj = open(path)
try:
    # do somdthing with fobj
finally:
    fobj.close()
```

The file will be closed  as soon as you leave the indention of the `with` statement, even in the case of an exception.

Comment: I keep having following error: `*** RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: Try increasing the limit:


    `import sys`

    `sys.setrecursionlimit(10_000)`

Comment: If I am still facing with the same error, would it be wise to increase `10_000` more?

Comment: Just try it out. If you increase too much, you program will crash. Looks like you have a recursive  data structure such as a s list that contains itself. You may need to fix this.

Comment: When I add more zeros should I add `_` again like: `1_000_000` ?

Comment: @alper Just like to add that this is probably nothing to to do with you code. and is instead an issue with `pickle`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134706/hitting-maximum-recursion-depth-using-pickle-cpickle