# PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'module'>: attribute lookup module on builtins failed

Tags: python, keras, pickle, prediction

Can we save any of the created LSTM models themselves? I believe that “pickling” is the standard method to serialize python objects to a file.  Ideally, I wanted to create a python module that contained one or more functions that either allowed me to specify an LSTM model to load or used a hard-coded pre-fit model to generate forecasts based on data passed in to initialize the model.

I tried to use it but gave me an error.

Code that I used:

```
    # create and fit the LSTM network
batch_size = 1
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(LSTM(50, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, look_back, 1), stateful=True)) 
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
for i in range(10):
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()

with open ('sequential.pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model,f)

pickle_in = open ('sequential.pickle','rb')
model = pickle.load(pickle_in)

# make predictions
trainPredict = model.predict(trainX, batch_size=batch_size)
model.reset_states()
testPredict = model.predict(testX, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model):

> **It is not recommended to use pickle or cPickle to save a Keras model.**
>
> You can use `model.save(filepath)` to save a Keras model into a single
>   HDF5 file which will contain:
>
> - the architecture of the model, allowing to re-create the model
> - the weights of the model
> - the training configuration (loss, optimizer)
> - the state of the optimizer, allowing to resume training exactly where you left off. You can then use `keras.models.load_model(filepath)`
>     to reinstantiate your model.

To save your model, you'd need to call `model.save`:

```
model.save('model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'model.h5'
```

Similarly, loading the model is done like this:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model('model.h5')
```

Comment: @coldspeed Great help. Appreciated.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677012/python-cant-pickle-type-x-attribute-lookup-failed?rq=1) post is answering that. And that `dill` works, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168420/how-to-dill-pickle-to-file).