# PySpark: Error "Cannot pickle standard input" on function map

Tags: pyspark, classification, pickle, rdd

I'm trying to learn to use Pyspark.
I'm usin spark-2.2.0- with Python3
I'm in front of a problem now and I can't find where it came from. 
My project is to adapt a algorithm wrote by data-scientist to be distributed. The code below it's what I have to use to extract the features from images and I have to adapt it to extract features whith pyspark.

```
import json

import sys


# Dependencies can be installed by running:

# pip install keras tensorflow h5py pillow


# Run script as:

# ./extract-features.py images/*.jpg


from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16

from keras.models import Model

from keras.preprocessing import image

from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input

import numpy as np


def main():

    # Load model VGG16 as described in https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1556

    # This is going to take some time...

    base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')

    # Model will produce the output of the 'fc2'layer which is the penultimate neural network layer

    # (see the paper above for mode details)

    model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=base_model.get_layer('fc2').output)


    # For each image, extract the representation

    for image_path in sys.argv[1:]:

        features = extract_features(model, image_path)

        with open(image_path + ".json", "w") as out:

            json.dump(features, out)


def extract_features(model, image_path):

    img = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(224, 224))

    x = image.img_to_array(img)

    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

    x = preprocess_input(x)


    features = model.predict(x)

    return features.tolist()[0]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

I have written the begining of the Code:

```
rdd = sc.binaryFiles(PathImages)
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet')    
model = Model(input=base_model.input, output=base_model.get_layer('fc2').output)
rdd2 = rdd.map(lambda x : (x[0], extract_features(model, x[0][5:]))) 
rdd2.collect()[0]
```

when I try to extract the feature. There is an error.

> ~/Code/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py in
>   save_file(self, obj)
>       623             return self.save_reduce(getattr, (sys,'stderr'), obj=obj)
>       624         if obj is sys.stdin:
>   --> 625             raise pickle.PicklingError("Cannot pickle standard input")
>       626         if  hasattr(obj, 'isatty') and obj.isatty():
>       627             raise pickle.PicklingError("Cannot pickle files that map to tty objects")
>
> PicklingError: Cannot pickle standard input

I try multiple thing and here is my first result. I know that the error come from the line below in the method extract_features:

```
features = model.predict(x)
```

and when I try to run this line out of a map function or pyspark, this work fine.
I think the problem come from the object "model" and his serialisation whith pyspark.
Maybe I don't use a good way to distribute this with pyspark and if you have any clew to help me, I will take them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might be right about the Model serialization. However, can you try broadcasting the model and accessing it within `extract_features`. For example, `BC_MODEL= sc.broadcast(model)` and within the extract (withoun passing the model as a parameter to the function) : `BC_MODEL.value.predict(x)`

Comment: Thank but I got the same error. broadcast doesn't work. I have a pickle error. I try to save the model like in this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289892/picklingerror-cant-pickle-class-module-attribute-lookup-module-on-builtin. It work on few images but with more than ten I have a memory issue.