# Is there a faster and efficient way to save a python dictionary?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, pickle

Using pickle, I am saving dictionaries every time a key value changes (or when a new key is added). I am assuming that pickle saves all the data including the keys and values that have not changed. Is there a way to selectively pickle data when key changes? Something more like what git does i.e. save only what has changed.

Comment: Lots and lots. Are you looking for a database, maybe, like SQLite? What needs to be saved and how does it need to be used?

Comment: It sounds like you want a database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pickle alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897345/pickle-alternatives)

Comment: How large are your dictionaries?

Comment: It can be a few GB. It would have been perfect if pickle checked if part of data has changed. Thanks for the alternatives. I will check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me as if pickle no longer fits your requirements. Have a look at the Pickle Alternatives as suggested by Amin.

Another possibilty would be a sqlite-based key-value store:
 [Use SQLite as a key:value store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237807/use-sqlite-as-a-keyvalue-store)